# Working with Fragments in Monodroid

Tags: c#, android-fragments, xamarin.android

My (albeit still limited as I'm just beginning) understanding of Fragments is that they are somewhat similar to usercontrols in *WPF* - and since I intent to reuse certain *GUI* elements, putting them into activities seems to result in a lot of duplicate code.

So, based on fragment example in the documentation, I tried making my own.

```
public class MyFragment: Fragment
{

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
            Log.Debug("SmartApp", "Dialer Fragment is in a view without container");
            return null;
        }

        input = container.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
//do some stuff like assigning event handlers, etc.

        return base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

And the activity that is supposed to host this fragment:

```
[Activity(Label = "My Activity")]
public class TestActivity: Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.my_layout);
    }
}
```

and finally the layout definition for this activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<fragment class="MonoDevelopTest.MyFragment"
        android:id="@+id/titles_fragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

When I debug this, I get an `InflateException` in `MyActivity.OnCreate` (on the `SetContentView` line). So, I'm not doing things right - what would be the proper way to have my desired layout loaded for the activity and hosting my fragment in it?

@edit: Aargh - as it so often happens, writing down the problem gives you a few new ideas. I wasn't very far away - my error was. All I had to change was add this as first line in `MyFragment.OnCreateView:`

```
View fragment = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.dialer, null);
```

And then I had to search on fragment for my controls, not container (which remained null).

The only thing I don't quite get is why in the *Xamarin* sample they check for `container == null` in `DetailsFragment.OnCreateView` (which is what had me going down the wrong route initially).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to change was add this as first line in MyFragment.OnCreateView:

```
View fragment = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.dialer, null);
```

And then I had to search on fragment for my controls, not container. I still don't quite understand why in the official sample they have check container for null in OnCreateView - but for now I'm only dabbling in phones, not tables so I'll have but one layout.